# Data loss between SQL Server and Datatable column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable, data-loss

I have a stored procedure that calculates employees time based on job tile and breaks it out by regular/overtime, Total hours, cost, and percentages.

I am loading the resulting table into a datatable on a webpage (C#.NET) to use as a datasource for a grid.  The code for SQL is:

```
ELSE IF @type = 'Reports_MH_WO_JobTitles'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TS_JT_R_O TABLE ([JobTitle] NVARCHAR(100),[R] DECIMAL(5,1),[O] DECIMAL(5,1), [Bill Rate] DECIMAL(18,2))

    -- Code Here to populate @TS_JT_R_O

    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [JobTitle]) [Sort]
    ,T.[JobTitle]
    ,SUM([R]) [R]
    ,SUM([O]) [O]
    ,SUM([R]+[O]) [TOTAL]
    ,CAST(SUM([Cost]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) [Cost]
    ,CAST(SUM([R]+[O])/( SELECT SUM([R]+[O]) FROM @TS_JT_R_O ) AS DECIMAL(6,5)) [HoursPer]
    ,CAST(SUM([Cost])/( SELECT SUM([COST]) FROM ( SELECT (SUM([R])*[Bill Rate])+(SUM([O])*[Bill Rate]*1.5) [COST] FROM @TS_JT_R_O GROUP BY [Bill Rate] ) Z ) AS DECIMAL(6,5)) [CostPer]
    FROM 
        ( SELECT [JobTitle],SUM([R]) [R],SUM([O]) [O],SUM([R]+[O]) [TOTAL], (SUM([R])*[Bill Rate])+(SUM([O])*[Bill Rate]*1.5) [Cost] FROM @TS_JT_R_O GROUP BY [JobTitle], [Bill Rate] ) T
    GROUP BY T.[JobTitle]
    UNION
    SELECT '999999999'[Sort], 'GRAND TOTAL' [JobTitle], SUM([R]) [R], SUM([O]) [O], SUM([R]+[O]) [TOTAL], CAST(SUM([Cost]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) [Cost],1,1
    FROM 
    ( SELECT [JobTitle],SUM([R]) [R],SUM([O]) [O],SUM([R]+[O]) [TOTAL], (SUM([R])*[Bill Rate])+(SUM([O])*[Bill Rate]*1.5) [Cost] FROM @TS_JT_R_O GROUP BY [JobTitle], [Bill Rate] ) T
    ORDER BY [Sort],[JobTitle]

END
```

The code behind for populating the grid:

```
    sqlStr = "WorkOrder_SelectStatements";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, cnn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Reports_MH_WO_JobTitles";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ddlWorkOrder.SelectedValue;
    if (rdpStart.SelectedDate != null)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtStart.Text;
    if (rdpEnd.SelectedDate != null)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEnd.Text;
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    grid.DataSource = dt;
    grid.DataBind();
```

While debugging the DataAdapter fills the DataTable but the columns for the "Cost" and the "CostPer" from SQL go into the DataTable as NULL.  Out of the missing data the only cell that populates is the 100% for the cost percentage for the UNION SELECT.

I am at a loss as to where only some of the data is dropped.  Any ideas where this data loss between SQL and the DataAdapter is coming from?

Screenshots:

SQL

[image: SQL Data Result Set]

Visual Studio Debug View

[image: Debug view from VS]

Web Page Resulting View

[image: Web Site]

Comment: What happens if you remove the type casting? For example, use this line: ,SUM([Cost]) as Cost

Comment: Removed the type cast for [Cost], [HoursPer], and [CostPer].  No change.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I even went as so far as to create a Temp table with the data types I want and filled it with the script above and did a select ALL against that table.  This created the same result.

Comment: Try column mappings for the data adapter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-datatable-and-datacolumn-mappings

Comment: This did not have any affect.

Comment: Is that SQL Screenshot the result of executing the procedure, or the result of you creating a temp table and filling it with a script outside the procedure? Are you allowed to edit the procedure?

Comment: I selected to modify the procedure, commented out the alter and parameters, created temp variables with the parameters passed in and ran it.  I wanted to ensure that the missing values where being calculated.  And yes I have full control of the database.